# GCF deployment failure (region/billing)

Tags: node.js, firebase, go, google-cloud-functions

I cannot deploy functions anymore, even on other projects.
I'm deploying, as always, with `gcloud functions deploy ...` and now I get this error

```
Failed to initialize region (action ID: 5a9a2fb704b2df80): Error when configuring GCS bucket gcf-sources-*bucket id*-us-central1 in project *my project name is here*. Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent
```

These projects never had billing, they are alive for almost 3 years and never had a problem deploying in go113 or node8

Answer (score 2):

Node.js 8 Firebase cloud functions are currently being phased out, as Node.js 8 was recently [marked end as "end-of-life"](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#end-of-life-releases) by the Node.js foundation.

Deployment of Node.js 8 functions will stop after February 15, 2021, and executions of deployed Node.js functions [will stop after March 15, 2021](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#functions-runtime).

If you've recently switched to Node.js 10 Firebase cloud functions, these require the Blaze pay-as-you-go billing plan and the Firebase CLI version ≥ 8.1.0. Using the Spark free tier, [you cannot deploy Node.js 10 Firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#expandable-21).

The error message "Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent" provides some information the cause of this issue.

Comment: I get the message **Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent** even through I've added the credit card info and targeting nodejs 8 with spark plan.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out Google has some problems

[Google Cloud Status](https://status.cloud.google.com/)

```
We are experiencing an issue with Google Cloud Storage infrastructure affecting multiple products beginning at Wednesday, 2020-08-19 21:15 US/Pacific.
```