# Problem deploying my functions to Google Cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a problem deploying my functions to Google Cloud:

How and message appears in Firebase CLI:

```
    + functions: Finished running predeploy script.
    i functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled ...
    + functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
    i functions: preparing functions directory for uploading ...
    i functions: packaged functions (85.85 KB) for uploading
    + functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
    i functions: current functions in project: Backup (us-central1), DashBoard (us-central1), dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment (us-central1)
    i functions: uploading functions in project: DashBoard (us-central1), Backup (us-central1)
    i functions: updating Node.js 10 (Beta) function DashBoard (us-central1) ...
    i functions: updating Node.js 10 (Beta) function Backup (us-central1) ...
    ! functions [DashBoard (us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Failed to initialize region (action ID: f22869a1fe22aba0): Error when configuring GCS bucket gcf-sources-366403583884-us-central1 in project testechatbot-2020. Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent
    ! functions [Backup (us-central1)]: Deployment error.
    Failed to initialize region (action ID: 2e3bfdf4820819aa): Error when configuring GCS bucket gcf-sources-366403583884-us-central1 in project testechatbot-2020. Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent
```

How and message appears on the Firebase console:

```
    Backup
    
    {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":7,"message":"Failed to initialize region (action ID: e0e457da63bedd16): Error when configuring GCS bucket gcf-sources-366403583884-us-central1 in project testechatbot-2020. Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent"},"authenticationInfo":
    
    DashBoard
    {"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":7,"message":"Failed to initialize region (action ID: 243073b0e1959dc3): Error when configuring GCS bucket gcf-sources-366403583884-us-central1 in project testechatbot-2020. Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent"},"authenticationInfo":
```

Comment: You should note the error message: *"The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent"*.  If this is surprising to you, contact Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: You probably upgraded to Node 10 as you received a notice indicating that Node 8 was being phased out. I know that's what I did, and a few weeks ago everything worked fine. Now, they're limiting free plans to Node 8, so I had to revert to Node 8 by editing package.json in my cloud functions project. This limitation of the Spark plan is mentioned here https://firebase.google.com/pricing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am new to Stack Overflow, so I am unable to mark a question as a duplicate or comment, so I am answering again here:

> Node.js 8 Firebase cloud functions are currently being phased out, as
> Node.js 8 was recently marked end as "end-of-life" by the Node.js
> foundation.
>
> Deployment of Node.js 8 functions will stop after February 15, 2021,
> and executions of deployed Node.js functions will stop after March 15,
> 2021.
>
> If you've recently switched to Node.js 10 Firebase cloud functions,
> these require the Blaze pay-as-you-go billing plan and the Firebase
> CLI version ≥ 8.1.0. Using the Spark free tier, you cannot deploy
> Node.js 10 Firebase cloud functions.
>
> The error message "Cause: The billing account for the owning project
> is disabled in state absent" provides some information the cause of
> this issue.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63605782/14167361) (my answer to a duplicate question).

Answer (score 1):

From the message you see "Cause: The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state absent."

The correct next step was already given by @Doug to contact Firebase [support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) as this forum cannot dig deeper into it.